# Code outside in for loop executing before execution in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sails.js, sails-mongo

here is my code snippet. I am trying to get details of my friends.friendsList is in reside within the user collection itself and there i am inserting users's id. So first i am fetching `userId`,then fetching each of their details.but my problem is i am not getting the values of `friendsDetails` outside the `fetchDetailsfunction`. I tried many time. i am new to node and sails js. i think its problem of asynchronous execution. How can i solve this problem?

```
getFriendsDetails:function(req,res){
        var userId = req.param('id');
        var friendsDetails=[];
        User.findOne({
            id: userId
        }).exec(function(err,user){
            var friendsIds=user.friends;
            friendsIds.forEach(function(id){

                User.findOne({
                        id: id
                    }).exec(function fetchDetails(err,Userdetails){

                        var obj={
                            id:Userdetails.id,
                            name:Userdetails.name,
                            pro_pic:Userdetails.profile_pic 
                        }
                        friendsDetails.push(obj);

                        console.log(friendsDetails);//Here consoling pushed data correctly.

                    });
                    console.log(friendsDetails);//here i am getting null array


            });
        });
```

Comment: This is normal behavior. Read a little bit here to find out about basics: https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/manage-async-nodejs-callback-example-code

Answer (score 0):

As hlozancic said, the behavior is just as expected. The `User.findOne` queries are asynchronous, so the code continues executing on the line after your callback function, so the `console.log(friendsDetails)` outside your `fetchDetails` function is called before any of those on the inside.

As a solution, you don't have to use `findOne` to search for multiple users; you can use a standard `find` which returns an array of users based on your search criteria, like this (also using the built-in `.then()/.catch()` syntax for simplicity's sake):

```
getFriendsDetails : function(req, res) {
    var userId = req.param('id');
    var friendsDetails = [];
    User.findOne({
        id: userId
    })
    .then(function(user) {
        var friendsIds = user.friends;
        return User.find({
            id: friendsIds
        })
    })
    .then(function(users) {
        users.forEach(function(friend) {
            friendsDetails.push({
                id: friend.id,
                name: friend.name,
                pro_pic: friend.profile_pic                 
            })
        })
        console.log(friendsDetails); // Should log list of friend details
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Error!", err);
    })
}
```